# Jmeter Socket closed error

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, socketexception

Configured the ff properties:

```
user.properties  

httpclient4.retrycount=1  
hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters

hc.parameters  

http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true 

HTTP Manager  
HTTP4 Client
```

Problem with JMeter which has set up with 14 threads

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:158)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:271)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:259)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:209)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.receiveResponseHeader(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:212)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:686)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:488)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:654)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:413)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1166)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1155)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:475)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:418)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What version of JMeter are you using ?

Comment: The version is JMeter 3.1